# How to add command line options to shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

How can I add command line options to an executable in a shortcut in Windows XP?

For example in the shortcut properties in target I have:

```
"c:\path\to\exe\pogram.exe"
```

I want to add some options:

```
"c:\path\to\exe\program.exe -option1 -option2"
```

However when I do this I get an error saying that the name specified in the target box is not valid.

Comment: People looking for a scripting solution, see e.g. [create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Have you tried to add in the Target field

```
"c:\path\to\exe\program.exe" -option1 -option2
```

Only the program path and name need to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Windows 7 strips the quotes and expands known executable paths. If you're trying to run CMD builtins (like piping) from a link, see http://superuser.com/questions/1089922/cmd-command-redirection-pipes-in-link-on-windows-7/1089923

Comment: Is there a list of all the possible arguments somewhere?

Comment: @Hashim: "all the possible arguments" to what, `cmd.exe`? [Here's](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) a link to those.

Comment: All the arguments/options that it's possible to pass to a program you want to run.

Comment: Also: Watch out for non-printable characters from copy-pasting. If the Target does not work for some reason, just make sure all "space" characters are actual spaces and not something else.

Answer (score 17):

**Place the switches after the quotes.**

Only the program path is kept in quotes due to spaces in the path. Something like `My Documents` will not resolve properly due to the space between the words, so quotes are needed. This is also why you probably won't find a program with multi-word switches (that are seperate) such as `--example switch`. You will usually see something like `--example-switch` instead because a space constitutes a separate program argument.

Comment: Is there a list of all the possible arguments somewhere?

Comment: @Hashim- The arguments would depend upon the program the shortcut is linking to. Check the documentation for your program to discover what arguments it will accept.

Answer (score 5):

Your quotes are in the wrong place.  The quotes only go around individual paths.  So move your ending quote back to the end of program.exe and leave -option1 -option2 outside of the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use shortcuts for direct access to a folder or a website.

**Folder:**

```
F:\CriticalFiles\MS_InternetAccess
```

**Internet:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet  Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.theguardian.com/world"
```

I use quotes around both arguments.
I am using these because Win10 seems to lose the start menu from time to time.