# Desktop shortcut to execute "ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache" inside of win7's run command

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I'm looking for a way have a shortcut on my desktop to execute "ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache" inside of Windows 7 "run" box.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don’t understand what the Windows 7 “run” box (or “run command”) has to do with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add arguments to the shortcut similar to how it is done for other programs and launchers. Take a look at this answer as it shows them doing so for another program, however it should work the same for you as well:

[Adding Command-Line Switches To Windows Shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/358565/adding-command-line-switches-to-windows-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention? If you want to run the "ie4unit.exe -cleariconcache" whenever windows starts you can create a bat file with that command and save it in the startup folder in start menu:

c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup