# How to add command line arguments to command line arguments in Windows shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I know I can add a command line argument/option to a shortcut this way; for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.a.com
```

So IE will connect to `a.com` when it starts up. What I would like to do is to get IE connecting to `a.com` when I call it through another program like the following:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.151 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.a.com
```

This does not work. IE starts up but doesn't go to `a.com`. It seems like the argument is either ignored or is understood as an argument of ForceBindIP instead (I'm not sure).

---

What I am trying to do is to create 2 IE shortcuts such each of them binds one IE window to one NIC and one particular website. So adding the `www.a.com` etc in its startup list won't help. OS is Windows 8.

Apologize if this has been asked and answered before. Please suggest keywords for searching if that's the case.

Comment: What is the other program that you are calling IE from. Most likely this will be a function of that program.

Comment: It is Force Bind IP,
[link](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/)

According to its page, the option available is "-i" which does something else.

Comment: The page does claim that arguments are allowed. Unless someone that has used that specific utility wanders along though, it is unlikely that anyone here can answer this question from prior experience. If I were you, I would try to contact the person that wrote the utility.

Comment: Thank you very much. So according to what you wrote, there is probably no general method to pass arguments (e.g., www.a.com) to the other argument ("link to iexplore.com") of an exe file that would work with any other exe file, not specifically with ForceBindIP.exe?

Comment: Starting a new process including what parameters to hand to that new process is always controlled by whatever application is starting the new process. In general, the people that write applications do a good job of this. In this case it looks like the author of the utility has at the very least attempted to do this. It is possible that you are simply making a syntax error. It is also possible that the author is passing the parameters in an odd way. You will need to talk to the author.

Comment: Can you create a batch file that says `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.a.com`, and then change the shortcut to say `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.151 foo.bat`?

Comment: That actually works. Thank you very much, Scott!

P.S. I also tried to create a Windows shortcut, instead of a batch file, to do the same thing, and called it through another shortcut
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.151 foo.lnk
That didn't work.

Comment: @Scott or Pawin, you wanna add the above comment as an Answer, so this thread can be marked as Answered? :)

Comment: @Lizz: OK, done.

Comment: Dup of http://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut. Intermediate bat/cmd file is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file (called, say, `foo.bat`) that says

> `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  www.a.com`

and then change the shortcut to say

> `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe  192.168.1.151  foo.bat`

This lets you work within ForceBindIP’s apparent restriction of handling only

> `ForceBindIP.exe`  *IP address* *full path to app*

on its command line (without accepting any parameters for the *app*), while also providing parameter(s) for Internet Explorer.  (You’ll note that [their web page](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip) shows only the above usage, although they don’t spell out the restriction.)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason ForceBindIP is ignoring first parameter, so do it like:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.1.151 "C:\Program
>   Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" foo www.a.com

Answer (score -1):

ForceBindIp takes 3 arguments for itself and searches them for IP/Interface, the program to start and the "-i" switch, which delays the injection of forcebind until the message queue is loaded (whatever this means).

So even when the 2 mandatory arguments ip and program are there but the third, optional -i switch is missing, it is discarding the third parameter (since it is none of the 3 known).

From the fourth parameter on, it parses every argument to the program. So something like `ForceBindIp ÌP FULLPATH garbage ARGUMENT1 ARGUMENT2` works.