# Access Launch Options in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How can I use "launch options" parameters on an application in Windows 10?

When I right click > properties an application file I don't see "launch options" anywhere.

I am logged in as admin.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut

Comment: When I do this it gives me an error so I was looking to edit it via the "launch options", altough I am not sure it will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250):

### Set Steam Launch Options

1. Navigate to your Steam installation (by default this is located at C:\Program Files\Steam)
2. Right-click on Steam.exe (this file is listed as an application and features the black and white Steam logo) and select Create Shortcut
   Right-click on the new shortcut and go to Properties
3. Select the Shortcut tab
4. In the **Target**: field add the launch options which you would like to use after the Steam.exe location (make sure to separate all launch options with a space - For example, " `-launchoption1` `-launchoption2`")
5. Click Apply and then OK to close the Properties window

Answer (score 0):

You see these options in steam , not in windows itself.
Open steam , click library , right click on the game , click properties and there you can find launch options