# Run a program from the File Explorer using default command line arguments

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I have a program I want to run, but every time I run it I want to use certain command line arguments. I don't know how to run a program from the File Explorer with command line arguments, so I always use the command prompt. These arguments are always the same, so is there a way to run an executable using default command line arguments?

Comment: You could create a batch file and use `start "" "C:\App\program.exe" "arg1" "arg2"` or whatever and pass it whatever default parameters in its logic and then just execute the batch to run those defaults. That's a quick and simple solution but there may also be a registry editing method too but I'd use a batch type solution myself more than likely based on what you explain here and my understanding.

Comment: [How to add command line options to shortcut?](https://superuser.com/q/29569/432690) I don't know Windows 10, I cannot tell if this method still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-Click the program and Create Shortcut.

Once the shortcut is created, right click the shortcut and click properties to edit it.

Change the “Target” to include the command line parameters.

Optionally, rename the shortcut so it better clarifies the intention of the shortcut.

Comment: Actually I prefer this over the batch file, thanks :)

Comment: @swimingduck Good deal!!!